# Trying to push code to specific branch on GitHub Online

Tags: git, github

I'm running into this weird problem. I have a branch in remote that I cloned from a branch online and I'm trying to push my changes to the online branch using "git push origin custom-loss" but then it says "error: src refspec custom-loss does not match any", but then when I do git pull origin custom-loss it says "Already up to date." So I know it's finding the branch online just not when I push.

Comment: What are the outputs of `git branch` and `git status`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error “src refspec custom-loss does not match any” means that you don't have a local branch called `custom-loss`.  When you run `git pull origin custom-loss`, it pulls the changes from the remote side's `custom-loss` branch into your current branch, but it doesn't necessarily create the branch for you if it doesn't exist.

It may happen to exist as `refs/origin/custom-loss` (which you would normally write as `origin/custom-loss`), but that's a remote tracking branch, not a normal branch.

If your branch is named something else (say, `foo`) and you want to push it to the remote `custom-loss` branch, you can say, `git push origin foo:refs/heads/custom-loss` and it will push your changes there.  You can also rename your branch with `git branch -m custom-loss` and then use your original command.